# How to iterate xml file , check with lxml if attribute exists and join it and its value to another variable?

Tags: python, xml, iteration, lxml

I've got a tree hierarchy xml list and my goal to iterate it and make three lists of dictionaries grantparent, parent, child like this [{[key:value],..}{}].

```
<Grandparent>
        <Name>Zavulon</Name>
        <age earthage = "80">4600</age>
        <height>342</height>
        <Parent>
            <name>Dan</name>
            <name>Daniel</name>
            <height>210</height>

            <Child>
                <name>XO</name>
                <name earthname = "Bob">Tringomurro</name>
            </Child>
         </Parent>
  </Grandparent>
```

It is an example. The real list is much larger and i dont know all the attribute names, so i think i need to write another function separated from iteration to check for attributes and join them as a string right to the value variable or make another key:value.

```
class Scanner():
    def __init__(self):
        self.dbxml = etree.parse('systems.xml')
        self.sysinfo = []   
        self.starinfo = []
        self.bodyinfo = []
    def attr_check(self,tag,text): # here i need to check the tag for attributes, .join it to text and than return back
        self.tag = tag
        self.text = text
        #!!! here i want to get attribute and assign new values but don't know how
        return  self.tag, self.text
    def get_fields(self): # This method should create a dictionary for each planet,star or system
        for system in self.dbxml.xpath('/systems/system'):                       

            stm = {}
            sn = {}
            bd = {}
            for star in system: 
                #here is where i call function
                checkstar = attr_check(star.tag, star.text)                               
                stm[checkstar[0]] = checkstar[1] 
                for sun in star:
                    #I'd like to call it here too     
                    sn[sun.tag] = sun.text
                    for body in sun:   
                        #And here                                               
                        bd[body.tag] = body.text

                 self.bodyinfo.append(bd)

            self.starinfo.append(sn)

            self.sysinfo.append(stm)

        return self.sysinfo, self.starinfo, self.bodyinfo
```

The problem is that key.tag doesnt have an attribute if i print it whithin iteration function and i dont know how to touch it. 
 So the output for one of the lists should look like [{ Name: Zavulon, age : 4600 earthage = 80}, ...] or make "earthage = "80" " another key:value pair.

P.S. I know that the whole concept isn't perfect yet. Some dict. pairs overwrite others, i'll try to manage it by myself and  if you'd like to give me a tip that would be great. ( i'm an amateur :)

Comment: I would see if you can use XSLT (which is exposed by lxml) to do the actual transformation instead of doing it in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found it ! To get key:value attributes from xml  i should use .attrib (not .tag) when iterating . There is no  need for checking function:)  Cheers!